# Visual Studio 2010 Tooltip Comments for C++ methods

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, tooltip, xml-comments

**My question**

How do I write comments for my class methods in C++ using Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 and make them appear in the tooltip? Maybe it should work, but I do not see my comments appear in the tooltip.

**An example**

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to write "///" and immediately going to appear what you want. Sorry if i didn't understand your question.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! My Visual Studio configuration was causing the problem.

Comment: That works fine for my own methods, but what about native .NET code? How do I get the tooltips to show those remarks?